# "$<-" and environments

Tags: r

Why doesn't the following work? Ie, why doesn't calling "$<-" on an environment have a visible effect outside of the function?

```
myAssign <- function(env, name, value) {
  "$<-"(env, name, value)
}
e <- new.env()
myAssign(e, "x", 1)
e$x  # NULL
```

And also

```
myAssign(e, "x", 1)$x  # NULL
```

Whereas, if we do this at the top level:

```
"$<-"(e, "x", 1)
e$x  # 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does have an effect, just not the one you're looking for!

```
> myAssign(e, "x", 1)
<environment: 0x1dcd198>
> ls(e)
[1] "name"
```

The reason is that `$<-` evaluates its second argument in a non-standard way (as it must, to get `x` instead of `eval(x)` in `e$x <- 1`, if that makes any sense. Try `env[[name]] <- value`